# Вопрос про область видимости

Tags: c++

Почему у нас есть функция, на пример, void h(){ int y=8;} и мы внутри мейна не можем сделать так h():: y чтобы не писать int y=8, как бы расширить область видимости?

Понимаю, что надобности так делать особо нет, но все же, интересно

Comment: Потому что вне функции `h()` никакой `y` не существует — это достаточная причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в этом абсолютно нет смысла. Зачем менять какие-то локальные переменные функции вне её:

1. Какой смысл вы этому вообще придаёте? Что тогда произойдёт. В какой момент она будет меняться?
2. Представьте на секунду, что такая возможность есть. Получается, мы бы тогда могли управлять внутренней кухней встроенных функций из библиотек, которые используют какие-то переменные, что может полностью сломать их работу.